# Use multiline string in Gitlab release-cli description

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to create a release in the gitlab-cli with a multiline description but when add one by yaml specs I get the following error:

```
Executing "step_release" stage of the job script
/bin/sh: eval: line 150: syntax error: unexpected newline
$ release-cli create --name "Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG" --description "Release created using the release-cli. # collapsed multi-line command
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2
```

**Job:**

````
create release:
    ...
    release:
        tag_name: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
        name: 'Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
        description: |-
            Release created using the release-cli.

            Maven dependency
            ```xml
            <dependency>
              <groupId>group</groupId>
              <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
              <version>$CI_COMMIT_TAG</version>
            </dependency>
            ```
````

(also tried with `>` and `|`)

I tried it manually with `\n` but that is literally added in the release as
`Release created using the release-cli.\n\n ...`

How do I create a release via the release-cli with a multiline (markdown) description?

Answer (score 1):

What I found that works is to use `<br />` to make it on a new line. Now I just do something like this:

```
...
script:
  - echo "Release of $CI_PROJECT_TITLE version $CI_COMMIT_TAG.<br />[Download link](https://example.com)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty unreadable workaround but it works.
(Note that multiline echo doesn't work either)

```
create release:
    ...
    image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
    rules:
    script:
        - echo "Running the release job for version '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'."
        - set -e
        - |
          echo "Release created using the release-cli." > release_notes.md
          echo "" >> release_notes.md
          echo "Maven dependency:" >> release_notes.md
          echo "\`\`\`xml" >> release_notes.md
          echo "<dependency>" >> release_notes.md
          echo "  <groupId>group</groupId>" >> release_notes.md
          echo "  <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>" >> release_notes.md
          echo "  <version>$CI_COMMIT_TAG</version>" >> release_notes.md
          echo "</dependency>" >> release_notes.md
          echo "\`\`\`" >> release_notes.md
    release:
        tag_name: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
        name: 'Release $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
        description: release_notes.md
```

Still searching for a better solution.